# Паттерн для preg_replace для скрытия email-ов?

Tags: preg_match, php, email

Так чтобы до символа @ оставалось 2 знака и 5 символов в конце

> ```
> blablabla@mail.com
> ***la@***l.com
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/.*(.{2})@.*(.{5})$/",'***$1@***$2',$email);
```

На коротком адресе (имя пользователя<2 или доменное имя<5) выдаст без изменений.